# face_recognition error: list index out of range

Tags: face-recognition

I have read up on this error and most conclude that it means that face_recognition is not detecting any faces in the frame. However, open cv is detecting faces within that same frame, so I am not sure if face_recognition is indeed not detecting any faces or I am receiving an IndexError for some other reason?

```
img=face_recognition.load_image_file('Roman.jpg')

roman_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]

group_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(group_image)

group_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(group_image)
size = len(group_encodings)

print("total faces "+str(size))
k = 0

for x in group_encodings:
  results = face_recognition.compare_faces([roman_encodings], x)
  if results == True:
    print("Face"+str(size-k)+"at",end='')
    print(group_locations)
  k+=1
```

It throws list index out of range error at roman_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]

I have used the same image elsewhere and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi done this method to detect faces first and then recognize based on percentage of accuracy.This worked well for me

```
bounding_boxes, _ = detect_face.detect_face(frame, minsize, pnet, rnet, onet, threshold, factor)
nrof_faces = bounding_boxes.shape[0]
if nrof_faces > 0:
    det = bounding_boxes[:, 0:4]
    img_size = np.asarray(frame.shape)[0:2]
    cropped = []
    scaled = []
    scaled_reshape = []
    bb = np.zeros((nrof_faces,4), dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(nrof_faces):
        #<Code for frame manipulation>
        predictions = model.predict_proba(emb_array)
        best_class_indices = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
        best_class_probabilities = predictions[np.arange(len(best_class_indices)), best_class_indices]
        # print(best_class_probabilities)
        if best_class_probabilities>0.6:
            #<detect as face>
```